# Referencing secrets in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

What is the difference between `env` and `envFrom` fields in kubernetes when referencing secrets? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the ["env:"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) sample which will load variables into container environment as environment variables which can referenced using "$DEMO_GREETING" then you will get "Hello from the environment"

```
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

Similarly you can load [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) as environment variable as below

```
  envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: mysecret
```

Here the secret will be loaded as environment variable and this can be referenced as $mysecret inside the container.